# C++: Inconsistent std::pow( type ) definition

Tags: c++, definition, pow

I am using the `std::pow(std::complex)` defined in `<cmath>`, which returns `nan`. I expected the following for the complex power implementation:

```
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
cout << std::pow(std::complex(0.0, 0.0), 0) // should return (1, 0), but returns (nan,nan)

cout << std::pow(0.0, 0) // e.g. returns 1.0 as expected!
```

Why is the `std::pow(..., 0)` chose differently for different number types? And what be the best way to use a uniquely defined power function for all types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0<sup>0</sup> is to be understood as a limit rather than an arithmetic expression you can evaluate directly.

On the set of real numbers, this limit "exists" (simplifying here) and is 1, so that's the result you get.

On the set of complex numbers on the other hand, you are approaching an essential singularity; there exists no single complex number you could assign to the limit 0<sup>0</sup>. `NaN` is thus the only reasonable result.

So if you need a consistent power function, treating 0<sup>0</sup> as NaN in the real case too would be the reasonable way to go, as setting  0<sup>0</sup> = 1 is somewhat dodgy in real arithmetic anyway; though less so than in the complex case.

---

Note that I somewhat simplified the math here, but I'll repeat the key point to take away: **no number exists that would be a meaningful result for 0<sup>0</sup> interpreted as the complex power function.**
This includes the number 1. For a mathematically more rigorous discussion, you might want to have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/ or another more math-focused resource.

Last, it is worth noting that the result of `std::pow(std::complex(0.0, 0.0), 0)` is implementation defined; the above is a justification for the reasonable choice your implementation made. However, from a strict C++-standard point of view and ignoring the math aspect of this problem, 1 would also be a compliant result, as would be pi, -∞ and 0.

Comment: Even on the reals, I dislike $0^0$ being though as something meaningful. Sure, $x^x$ converges to 1 as x goes to 0, but it is only one of many paths. Think for instance of $lim_{x->0} 0^x$ and $lim_{x->0} 0^x$.

Comment: I disagree. In the question it is clear that the "complex^integer" case is meant. Not the "complex^complex" one. Note the use of "0" instead of "0.0" in the exponent. "z^n" is clearly 1 for n = 0. Otherwise complex power series would not make sense and a whole area of mathematics would not work.

Comment: @YSC I will not argue against that. I'd say that's just one of the simplifications the implementations use to model the world of mathematic, such as setting sqrt(-1) to the imaginary unit. Anyway, it is more reasonable in the real case than in the complex.

Comment: @BaummitAugen And I agree with your answer, just a bit of nitpicking.

Comment: @AndreasH. `std::pow` from `<complex>` operates on complex numbers only, and the `std::complex` number `0` does not encode its exact integral nature nor the direction from which it was reached. So in the context of C++, which naturally does not exactly represent either real nor complex arithmetic exactly, your comment does not change anything.

Comment: @AndreasH. Also note that setting x^0 to 1 globally in power series is a convention for ease of notation, not a meaningful definition of 0^0 in general.